# Python-Child class triggers parent

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to modify a declared object on parent from child object in python. I know that in java is possible to modify a parent object from a child by passing the parent as parameter when initializing the child object. I dont need to inherit everything from parent to child, I just need the child to show and hide frames declared on parent. For example in Java.

```
public class Parent(){
    public Child1 objtchild1;
    public Parent(){ ]
        Child2 panel = new Child2(this);
        Child1 objtchild1 = new Child1();
}
public class Child1 (){
     public int var = 1;

}
public class Child2 () {
    private Parent parent;
    public Child(Parent parent)  {
        this.parent = parent;
        parent.objtchild1.var=2;//Modify parent child object

}
```

I want to apply Model view controller where the view interact with the controller. Just like in the following url but in python.
[MVC codeprojects.com example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25057/Simple-Example-of-MVC-Model-View-Controller-Design)
Is the example above on Java possible in python?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Right now the solution has to be based on our interpretation of your assumptions rather than what the code actually is. The code may not necessarily match your assumptions.

Comment: My interpretation is that you're asking a simple question in a complicated way. No way to be sure until you provide [mcve].

Comment: Sorry about that. I just minimized my question of what I need to apply in my python project.

Comment: How is this related to tkinter?

Comment: I dont know what you mean of how is this related to tkinter? I want to apply Model view controller in python were the view interacts with the controller to pass click events. Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of your java code in python is:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # make sure to make objtchild1 first, as panel will try and alter it
        self.objtchild1 = Child1()
        self.panel = Child2(self)

class Child1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = 1

class Child2(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        # modify parent child object
        self.parent.objtchild1.var = 2
```

Comment: Thanks you save me hours of researching. I'm using pycharm and when I typed self.parent. it didnt give me any hints. It works, many thanks.